# Obj-C: Recursion: Making new objects on stack or use mutability

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, recursion, heap-memory

My question is this. In the code you see bellow, my second param is a `NSString*` and as I recursively get objects from the array and adds them to the `buildDescription` parameter I use the method `stringByAppendingFormat` which as I understand - creates a new object on the heap. Would it be better if I had an mutable string in the parameter and then use some other methods to append the new variables? as all objects in Obj-C are created on the heap, is this the preferred way of doing recursion, and what are the benefits for both approaches? of course It demands less memory just passing pointers to an mutable object.

```
+ (NSString *)makeDescriptionRecur:(NSMutableArray *)stack: (NSString *) buildDescription
{
    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];

    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
    {
        return [self makeDescriptionRecur:stack:
               [buildDescription stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ ", topOfStack]];

    } else if  ([topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
```

Comment: "Would it be better" how are we measuring goodness?

Comment: Graham: I don´t know - that is why I am asking.

Comment: @TomLilletveit Maybe space complexity, and then it would.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be better if I had an mutable string in the parameter and then use some other methods to append the new variables?

At least that wouldn't take `O(n ^ 2)` in memory, just `O(n)`. Maybe a bit more "optimal".